# Getting a string from a Regex?

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to get the opposite of a Regex? To put this simply it's for a routing engine...
It's all set up fine, but I'm writing a function to build URLs for links. Here's a routes.php file:

```
 class Router {

     /*
      * @var urls Contains info about routes
      * @format '{^REGEX(?<url_paramaters>$}' => array('ControllerClassName', 'ActionName', array/string('method(s)'))
      */

     var $urls = array(
        array('{^$}' => array('PagesController', 'index')),
        array('{^contact$}' => array('PagesController', 'contact', 'get')),
        array('{^about$}' => array('PagesController', 'about', 'get')),
        array('{^users/(?<user_id>\d+)$}' => array('UsersController', 'show')),
     );
  }
```

Right. SO that's all working fine. The dispatcher matches the URL against the regex, then dispatches it using the array following the Regex.
Here's my URL builder function... currently:

```
function build(array $resource = null) {    
    $routes = new Router;
    $controller = ucwords((isset($resource['controller'])) ? $resource['controller'] : $GLOBALS['controller']) . "Controller";
    $action = (isset($resource['action'])) ? $resource['action'] : 'index';
    // Loop through the routes to find the right Regex using the callback
    foreach($routes->urls as $route) {
        $regex = array_keys($route);
        $regex = $regex[0]; //Eg/ ^users/(?<user_id>\d+)$
        $callback = $route[$regex];
        // ?? Something in here.
    }
}
```

Imagine the $resource could contain stuff like "user_id" => 123. How could I go through the regex setting the capture groups to the right value?
I hope I worded this well enough!
Thanks in advance,
Brad

Comment: Such a method does not exist. You could use the capture groups for reconstructing the original subject only in the simplest of cases (no unspecific `.*` matches, but only fixed strings like in your case). While this wish comes up once in a while, nobody has coded even the simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```
preg_match('@/users/(?P<userId>\d+)/@Uis', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'], $matches);
// url: /users/1/
// $matches['userId'] = 1
```

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier doesn't make much sense if there is no `.` metacharacter to affect.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ordinary string concatenation and prepare an ordinary php map (instead of attempting to convert the regexpressions into one). For example:

```
// if $resource contains the capture groups
$keys = implode(",", array_keys($r = $resource));

// you would need an if-tree or switch to avoid notices here
$map = array(
    "user_id" => "users/$r[user_id]",
    "PagesController,contact,get" => "contact",
    "" => "",
}
return $map[$keys];
```

You see that the regex URL mapping is not reversible alone with the capture groups. You need other clues for "contact" and "about" pages. I've used the routing parmeters here as example. You could however simply create an unused capture group in your original regex:

```
array('{^(?<contact>contact)$}' => ...
```

Comment: @Brad: Post it as answer for anyone else who stumbles upon this question.

Comment: Yeah I'm new here. I tried to add it as a comment. Doh. It's up as an answer now! :P

Comment: @mario This question doesn't have a great title, but I am not sure that I understand the question.  Are you able to give the question a more indicative title?

Answer (score 0):

Think I've got it. It's probably a pretty bad solution but here it is anyway. PS. Please optimize it if you can! Ta.

```
function build(array $resource = null) {

  $routes = new Router;
  $controller = ucwords((isset($resource['controller'])) ? $resource['controller'] : $GLOBALS['controller']) . "Controller";
  $action = isset($resource['action']) ? $resource['action'] : 'index';
  // Loop through the routes to find the right Regex using the callback
  foreach($routes->urls as $route) {
    $regex = array_keys($route);
    $regex = $regex[0]; // ^users/(?<user_id>\d+)$
    $callback = $route[$regex];
    if($controller == $callback[0] && $action == $callback[1]) {
    $url = substr($regex, 2, -2);
    foreach($resource as $key => $value) {
      $url = preg_replace("/\??\(\?<".$key.">[^\)]+\)\??/", $value, $url);
      $url = preg_replace("/\)?\(?\??/", "", $url);
    }
    break;
    }
  }

  return "/".$url."/";

}
```